# Debug Yii 1.1 using VSCode and Docker

Tags: php, docker, yii, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I want to ask about debugging Yii 1.1 applications. I've tried implementing the answers on StackOverflow and other websites, but my VSCode still can't debug the application, the breakpoints that have been set are never read at all. I am using Docker to run Yii.

Here are the details of the file I used.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: php72
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.31-oracle
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '123456'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '123456'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test_db'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:

volumes:
  db_data:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions gd xdebug pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql mongodb mbstring zip


EXPOSE 80
```

**xdebug.ini**

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"
```

**launch.json**

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:8001"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/../../",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my project structure:

[image]

I access my apps in a browser with `localhost:8000`, then I try to turn on the VSCode debugger, but this is the result:

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated.

Is there any missing configuration?

Comment: 1) Make some page (URL endpoint) where you call `xdebug_info();` and call it via browser (the way you are trying to debug your code). Double check that the actual Xdebug settings are what you are expecting (show the screenshots here as well, in case there will be more mismatches). Also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw 2) If your code is inside the Docker then better remove `xdebug.discover_client_host=1` line.

Comment: 3) Per your 2nd screenshot (Xdebug log bits) Xdebug tries to connect to `192.168.208.1:9003` first (your autodetected IP) and then falls back to `xdebug.client_host` .. which is `localhost` and NOT the expected `host.docker.internal`. That's because you are using the Xdebug v2 parameter name `xdebug.remote_host` instead of v3 name `xdebug.client_host` (check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide ) -- that's the most obvious thing that you could spot from doing #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After watching several videos on how to setup Xdebug for an application running inside a docker container, I finally found the answer that works for my case.

I changed my `docker-compose.yml` to be like this:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: php72
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" // Add extra host for docker
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html // this is the remote path where my apps installed
      - ./xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.31-oracle
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '123456'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '123456'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'wms_test'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:

volumes:
  db_data:
```

And as per as @LazyOne advise, since I am using Xdebug 3 I have change my `xdebug.ini` also to be like this:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.idekey="VSCODE"
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug_remote.log
```

And the important part, after watching this YouTube video [Setup Xdebug WITH DOCKER and debug in VSCode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=it7JQKPfWTU) I've figured out what is missing in my previous setup, and that is the `pathMapping`. So I've changed my `launch.json` to be like this:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html" : "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    
    ]
}
```

And voila that work like a charm:

[image]